# Access SQL Server 2008 R2 from a remote location

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, remote-access

I have remote access enabled in SQL Server at my work network, which is on my "server". In the office, I have my desktop machine which I can use SQL Server Management Studio to access - no problems. I can use `telnet [LOCAL_IP] 1433` with no problems.

When I am at home, I want to access the SQL Server too. I can `PING [EXTERNAL_IP]` address to the office fine (which is a router), but can't `telnet [EXTERNAL_IP] 1433`. So my machine can't access it when using SQL Server Management Studio.

I thought it was a router firewall issue, I have modified the router firewall to let my IP address through on TCP and UDP on ports 1433 and 1434 both source and destination. I've also tried letting my home IP through on all ports too, and still nothing. I've also tried to disable the firewall on the windows server at work.

I can set up RDP fine though....so I am thinking something I don't know about in SQL Server is the problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions to try please?

Thx

Comment: Give a try, to use IP instead of Server name.

Comment: Thanks, have always used the IP rather than server name and doesn't make any difference either way.